# CSV Helper, Write List of Expando Objects with Properties Keys Sorted

Tags: c#, .net, csvhelper

I am writing a csv file using CSV helper

```
var entries = new List<ExpandoObject>();
ExpandoObject dynamic = GetVersionInfo(list.Id.ToString(), $"{file.MajorVersion}.0");
entries.Add(dynamic);
using (var writer = new StreamWriter("file.csv"))
using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
     var writeList = new List<dynamic>();
     writeList.AddRange(entries);
     csv.WriteRecords(writeList);
 }
```

this code works fine and I can see a csv file has been created but columns data is not in correct order. for example

[image]

Version Date is being written in Document Owner column. Reason for this mismatch is that I am using expando objects and order of the properties in the expando object is not in a proper sequence.
In first object Version Date is at number 3 in expando object while it is at number 4 in 2nd object.

I tried to sort the properties with this method but I get error in generating the csv, for example

```
writeList.AddRange(entries.Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.Key).ToList()));
csv.WriteRecords(writeList); //exception here
```

Exception I get is

> Types that inherit IEnumerable cannot be auto mapped. Did you accidentally call GetRecord or WriteRecord which acts on a single record instead of calling GetRecords or WriteRecords which acts on a list of records?

how can I sort and also write a collection of Expando objects  in a CSV file?

Comment: That means *your objects* don't have the properties you think they do, or that the order changes. What does `GetVersionInfo` do and why does it return a dynamic object when the properties are fixed? At the very least you should post enough code to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `entries.Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.Key).ToList()` is you no longer have a `List<ExpandoObject>`, but `IEnumerable<List<KeyValuePair<String,Object>>>`  There might be a more concise way to do this, but you need to get it back to `List<ExpandoObject>`.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var entries = new List<ExpandoObject>();
    dynamic obj1 = new ExpandoObject();
    obj1.Version = 11;
    obj1.Modified = new DateTime(2017,9,18);
    obj1.VersionDate = new DateTime(2016,6,29);
    obj1.DocumentOwner = "Unknown";

    dynamic obj2 = new ExpandoObject();
    obj2.Version = 1;
    obj2.Modified = new DateTime(2021, 3, 17);
    obj2.DocumentOwner = "Emergency Management Plan";
    obj2.VersionDate = new DateTime(2019, 1, 4);
    
    entries.Add(obj1);  
    entries.Add(obj2);
    
    entries = SortEntries(entries);

    //using (var writer = new StreamWriter("path\\to\\file.csv"))
    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(Console.Out, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        var writeList = new List<dynamic>();
        writeList.AddRange(entries);
        csv.WriteRecords(writeList);
    }
}

public List<ExpandoObject> SortEntries(IList<ExpandoObject> entries)
{
    var newList = new List<ExpandoObject>();
    
    foreach (var entry in entries)
    {
        var x = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, Object>;
        
        var sorted = entry.OrderByDescending(y => y.Key);

        foreach (var item in sorted)
        {
            x.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
        }
        
        newList.Add((ExpandoObject)x);
    }
    
    return newList;
}
```